# coordinate of line through half triangle

Tags: python

I have a question about triangle geometrics: I want to find the (x,z) coordinates of the end point of the red line, shown in the image. For other details see image. Can somebody help me with the formulas needed to find the coordinate? Hope somebody can help me[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4iFW.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a formula, not programming.  You may find [math.se] more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red line has the equation `x + z = 5`.

So then find the point on this line which has distance 20 from (0,0) and x is positive - this is apex of the triangle.

Then find the point which is 20 away from that point. Or just compute (x0-20/sqrt(2), z0+20/sqrt(2)) where (x0,z0) is the apex.

Answer (score 1):

The middle point between (a,b) and (c,d) is ((a+c)/2, (b+d)/2).

On your picture, it is (2.5, 2.5).

Comment: I mean at the end of the red line, not the middle point of the line between 0,0 and 5,5

Comment: There is no end to a line, do you mean at the intersection of the two longer sides?

Comment: (0,0), (x,z) and (5,5) all have distance 20 from the apex of the triangle and (x,z) is on the bisector.